# If systems of linear equations are equivalent, does the following computation hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given the matrices $A, A', B$ and vectors $d, d', b$. Suppose the systems $Ax=d$ and $A'x=d'$ are equivalent and the matrices $A, A'$ have full rank. Furthermore assume that there exist solutions $y$ and $y'$ to $(A+B)y=d+b$ and $(A'+B)y'=d'+b$ and that $A+B$ and $A'+B$ have full rank.

Can we argue that because of the equivalency of the systems $Ax=d$ and $A'x=d'$ the equality $y=y'$ holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take $A=2I_n$, $A'=I_n$, $d$ any nonzero vector, $d'=1/2. d$, $B=I_n$, $b=0$.

We end up with  the two systems $3y=d$ and $2y'=d'=1/2. d$.

They both have unique solutions $y=1/3.d$ and $y'=1/4.d$, which are distinct since $d\neq 0$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. If I understand correctly, your answer is based on the fact, that I did not specify if the matrices $A$ and $A'$ are invertible. Assume, they are. Then we cannot take any non-zero element of the kernel.

Comment: there are still counterexamples. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Tahnk you very much for your effort

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!